# LEFT JOIN not quite working

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables: `users` and `changes`. I want to keep track of the number of changes that each user makes. Currently I am doing it in two separate statements combined with PHP:

```
// Get all users
$stmt = GlobalContainer::$dbh->prepare("SELECT 
        id, username, realname
    FROM 
        users
    ORDER BY role_id, realname");
$stmt->execute();
while ($user = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $users[$user['id']] = $user;
    $users[$user['id']]['changes'] = 0;
}

// Get number of changes for each user
$stmt = GlobalContainer::$dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`, user_id 
    FROM 
        changes
    GROUP BY user_id");
$stmt->execute();
while ($changes = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $users[$changes['user_id']]['changes'] = $changes['count'];
}
```

This works perfectly, but I think it would be neater if I just combined it into one query. This is what I have:

```
SELECT 
        users.id, users.username, users.realname, count(changes.user_id) as `count`
    FROM 
        users
    LEFT JOIN `changes` ON users.id = changes.user_id
    GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY `count` ASC
```

However for some reason it is skipping all but one of the users with 0 changes even though there are several. There are also several users that have 3 changes each and it is showing all of them correctly. How can I get this query working so that it shows all users with 0 changes?

Comment: Can you post data? Didnt understood what do you mean by showing user with 0 changes.

Comment: changes.user_id would come back null if there are no matching entries in that table. Sometimes nulls mess up aggregates like COUNT(). You could try replacing null with zero inside the COUNT().

Comment: This seems to fix it: `GROUP BY users.id` instead of `GROUP BY changes.user_id`. Maybe someone could post an answer explaining *why* because I really don't know.

Comment: Is this about right? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52c90/1/0

Comment: @JasonSperske yes, looks about right. I can update with my create statements if you want.

Comment: If your drop count and group by and re execute (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52c90/4) you can see what is happening, you are grouping your nulls

Comment: Thanks Jason. Also a good answer, took time to explain in sql fiddle upvote. should submit as answer!

Comment: Agreed with @Hituptony

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough SQL to fix this though :P (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52c90/5) Maybe someone else can cross the finish line :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it looks like a recently deleted answer was the correct one.  Here is a breakdown (and a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52c90/7)).  The original query was grouping the `nulls` into a single result.  The easy answer is to group by a value that is not null. This makes the final query look like this:

```
SELECT 
        `users`.id, `users`.username, `users`.realname, count(changes.user_id) as `count`
    FROM 
        `users`
    LEFT JOIN `changes` ON users.id = changes.user_id
GROUP BY `users`.id;
```

Comment: right because of the left join - the values in changes table COULD be null, good catch.

Comment: I hope I'm not stepping on anyone's toes by re-posting a down voted answer

Comment: I agree - deleted my answer when it was downvoted to review the question as I thought I might have misread it..

Comment: @dugas, I upvoted both of you, but Jason's answer explains why this is what I needed to do, so I accepted his. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

Change your group by to:

```
GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.realname, count(changes.user_ID) from `changes` as `count` from users
left join `changes` on users.id = changes.user_id
group by users.id;
```

Your count is throwing off your results, you can nest that in a subquery to exclude it from your left join, which is in turn only returning rows where count(changes.user_id) and combining them into one record. If you use a subquery you can effectively get the count of the changes.user_id without effecting your left join.

Comment: if you find the sub query returns the same results. I stand corrected.

Comment: This actually returns the same value for each user. Looks like the total from all rows.

Comment: Now it's a syntax error `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from users left join changes on users.id = changes.user_id group by us' at line 1`